# Warning: string 'prediction_none' has no default translation

Tags: android, gradle, translation, android-resources

When I am run an android project downloaded from github, it says Warning: string 'prediction_none' has no default translation.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

> [String resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html#resources) The string resources for a project are contained in strings.xml files. Your project has a default strings.xml file that contains string resources in the default language for your app, which is the language you expect most of your app users to speak. You can also have translated strings.xml files that contain string resources for other languages that you want your app to accommodate.

The warning is shown because the app have more than one languages and there is a key ('prediction_none') that no exists on the main file of strings (default language) or vice versa.